# Using WSTP to connect a C process to local and remote kernels simultaneously

Tags: kernel, mathlink-or-wstp, remote-access

Is it possible for a C program to communicate (via WSTP) with both a Mathematica kernel running on its machine, and a remote one?

For context: I use a local Mathematica kernel which talks to a remote C process (via WSTP) which runs all the heavy computation. These computations involve modifying big data sets which live entirely in the memory of the remote C process. I now need to perform some calculations in *Mathematica* on these data sets; sending the data back and forth between the remote C process and my local Mathematica kernel is untenably slow.
It would be much better if instead, I could send the Mathematica expressions themselves to the remote C process, which would evaluate them on its data by passing the data and expression to a *local* Mathematica kernel.

This way, the big data sets don't need to be shared across a network; they would only be passed between the C program and the local (to it) kernel. The (small) result of the analysis would then be sent back to my (remote) kernel.

Is that at all possible using WSTP? It's not obvious to me how the C code can communicate with multiple kernels of any kind, since there's only one MathLink instance in the global namespace (as `stdlink`).

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you need to do it from scratch using the MathLink API. You can't use the simplified method with `mprep` and template files, where argument translation and return is handled mostly automatically for you.

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way. I'd simply use a remote kernel to connect to this executable.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for the heads-up about MathLink, I'll check it out! Your second comment doesn't make much sense to me; I *can't* use only a remote kernel because that would involve sending remotely the huge data sets, as is the premise of the question

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment. Run everything on the same computer, both Mathematica and the C program. Either both on your computer or both on the remote computer.

Comment: MathLink and WSTP are different names for the same thing. What you are asking is possible, but it is a lot of trouble and requires advanced MathLink programming.

Comment: @Szabolcs hopefully I'm getting closer to understanding you; do you mean that I should (from my local MMA kernel) connect directly to a *remote* kernel which itself connects to the (to it, local) C process?

Comment: I mean that you should never connect to anything remote. Run everything on the same computer.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't; the context of my question is that the C process must run on another machine (it's doing the "heavy computation" and using remote hardware)

Comment: So run everything on the remote machine.

Comment: "*everything*"? Would I then use magic to conjure the results back to the local machine? Do you think it's possible to use WSTP instead of magic, as per my question?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, nor do I understand most of your comments. The only reasonable interpretation I can think of is that you believe that you can only run Mathematica on the local machine, maybe because you want a GUI. This is not true, you can run it in command line mode on the remote machine (which is the right way if you process a lot of data), or you can connect your local front end to a remote kernel (not recommended due to robustness concerns, but still much better than what you are trying to do.)

Comment: If you want to save time and effort, run the kernel in command line on the remote machine. I assume you know how to use SFTP to transfer data back and forth. You only need a bit of flexibility, not "magic".  If you want to spend a lot of time and effort for little gain, look at the `factor.cxx` MathLink example on how to call a Mathematica kernel from a C program.

Comment: The premise of my question was that I must run a kernel locally, and a C process remotely, and whether an additional kernel local to the C process is feasible. Your speculation that I don't realise the kernel can be used from the command line, and that my situation allows everything to be run on the remote machine, is baseless and orthogonal to my question. Your first comment says "yes, it's possible, but you need to do it from scratch using the MathLink API". Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: I did, look at `factor.cxx` to get started.

Comment: This would also be a good reading for you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Never questioning the premise is not what is usually the most helpful for the OP. You did not give any justification for wanting to split the computation between remote and local, either in the original post or the comments.